# Return an integer/String from NPAPI plugin to JavaScript(Not using FireBreath)

Tags: javascript, plugins, npapi

Could anyone please explain with a sample...?

How can I return an integer/String  from NPAPI plugin(**Not using FireBreath**) to JavaScript?
I searched a lot ..but can't get a relevant answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.
Returning a string from NPAPI plugin

`char* npOutString = (char *)pNetscapefn->memalloc(strlen(StringVariable) + 1);`

`if (!npOutString)
    return false;
strcpy(npOutString, StringVariable);
STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(npOutString, *result);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a Scriptable class of NPObject: [Simple class definition and implementation](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/08/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-three/)

You can this post use in Firefox/Chrome browser. Its very similar to your question and has code for the invoke and the JavaScript/html. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231328/scriptable-plugin-error-calling-method-on-npobject).

If you have not read through at least part 1-3 of taxillian's blog on plugins, I would say it is a must read. Read carefully a lot of info I have missed by skimming by when reading.

[Part 1](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/)

[Part 2](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/05/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-two/)

[Part 3](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/08/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-three/)

Comment: As he says; in particular you need to create a NPVariant with the value you want.  int32 is easy (see http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/source/browse/trunk/headers/npruntime.h#155 for a helper macro), string is slightly harder because you need to allocate the string using NPN_MemAlloc.  See http://npapi.com/memory

Comment: Thanks..I just returned an integer value.
One more thing is I just want to return a char array to javaScript.
How can it possible?
char Map[50][50] = {0};
this is that array..I read your tutorials,I can't use fireBreath because of some dependency issues with binaries.
so I'm a newbie to NPAPI. Hope you will help..
Could you place some sample?

Comment: I have not returned an array personally, but this seems to be you same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078250/return-array-from-npapi-plugin-to-java-script