# How to return an integer from NPAPI plugin to JavaScript

Tags: macos, safari, npapi, firebreath

I am writing a safari plugin with NPAPI. 
How can I return an integer from NPAPI plugin(Not using FireBreath) to JavaScript?
javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function run() {
    var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");
    var number = plugin.getBrowserName();
    alert(number);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<embed width="0" height="0" type="test/x-open-with-default-plugin" id="pluginId">
<button onclick="run()">run</button>
</body>
</html>
```

plugin code:

```
bool plugin_invoke(NPObject *obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result) {
// Make sure the method called is "open".
NPUTF8 *name = browser->utf8fromidentifier(methodName);
if(strcmp(name, plugin_method_name_getBrowserName) == 0) {
  //what can i do here?
}
return true;
```

}

How to return a number from plugin.getBrowserName()?

Plz help!

I am find this thread:[Return an integer/String from NPAPI plugin to JavaScript(Not using FireBreath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837946/return-an-integer-string-from-npapi-plugin-to-javascriptnot-using-firebreath),
but i don't know where are these code

```
char* npOutString = (char *)pNetscapefn->memalloc(strlen(StringVariable) + 1);
if (!npOutString) return false; strcpy(npOutString, StringVariable); 
STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(npOutString, *result);
```

put.

Comment: Depending on `utf8fromidentifier` is suboptimal, it's better to use something like `static const NPIdentifier id = browser->getstringidentifier("foo"); if (methodName == id) { ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at http://npapi.com/tutorial3?

The return value goes in the NPVariant* result.  Go look at the [docs for NPVariant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPVariant) and you'll see there is a type and then a union for different types of data. The string code you're talking about would go in place of your "//what can i do here?" comment.  To return an integer, you'd do this:

```
bool plugin_invoke(NPObject *obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result) {
// Make sure the method called is "open".
NPUTF8 *name = browser->utf8fromidentifier(methodName);
if(strcmp(name, plugin_method_name_getBrowserName) == 0) {
  result->type = NPVariantType_Int32;
  result->intValue = 42;
}
return true;
```

You can also use the *_TO_NPVARIANT macros (documented at the link above for [NPVariant docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPVariant)) like so:

```
bool plugin_invoke(NPObject *obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result) {
// Make sure the method called is "open".
NPUTF8 *name = browser->utf8fromidentifier(methodName);
if(strcmp(name, plugin_method_name_getBrowserName) == 0) {
  INT32_TO_NPVARIANT(42, *result);
}
return true;
```

If you look at the [source for the INT32_TO_NPVARIANT macro](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/source/browse/trunk/headers/npruntime.h#155) you'll see it just does the same thing I did above, so the two are equivilent.

Comment: excellent... now please mark the answer =] (that's the outline of a checkmark by the question? click on it if this is the answer)